# Python function calling a variable from another function. But why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I know this one is pretty duplicated however:

```
def func1():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    return a

def func2():
    b = func1()
    print(b.a[0])

func2()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I WANT TO use `'.'` dot function(syntax) to access variables declared in other functions like :

```
print(b.a[0])
or
print(b.a)
```

should print out:

```
1
or
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Wouldn't it make things so much easier?

And I know this can be done by using `class` or many other ways too.

But why won't it work this way? Are there any 'must' reason(s) behind this way of access? Will it make Python vulnerable? or will it make python unstable?

I wasn't able to find a perfect, concise, clear, accurate explanation for this accessing issue.

Many Thanks.

---

to be more accurate for @Goyo

```
def func():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]

def func2():
    b = func()
    b.a[0] = "Not Working"
    print(b)

func2()
```

or

```
def func3():
    from . import func
    b = func()
    b.a[0] = 'Not working either'
    print(b)

func3()
```

I just feel it is more instinctive way of writing codes.
Maybe it is just me.

Comment: In Python, a function that doesn't return anything actually returns `None`.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're considering an issue, or what "this" is that can be done with a class.

Comment: Are you asking why declaring a local variable in a function doesn't add it as an attribute to `None`? Or why a function without a `return` statement doesn't implicitly return an object containing all the functions local variables instead of returning `None`? Or something else?

Comment: I think they're asking why executing a function doesn't automatically return an object which has all the local variables of the function as attributes. ... Because that is not what functions are for.

Comment: Now your code doesn't agree with the output you claim that it produces.

Comment: Error should be now: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: `func1` returns a list, so `b` is that list. I think your next stop should be [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I am dyslexic. molbdnilo

Comment: @user10874790 Oh, I'm sorry. You're writing better than most people, so I had no idea.

Comment: Why are you changing your question after accepting an answer? Does the accepted answer actually answer your question or not?

Comment: @Goyo Not extremely precisely. However, the chosen one at least directed the area where I was questioning at. And later I read more the replies and the answers, I assume that this is something can't be answered unless answered by Python developers. And I was hoping if any Python or other language developers sees my question. That's why I edited my question to deliver my intention. Apology if any of that confuses any.

Comment: I do not think it makes your intention any clearer but actually the opposite. Anyway, what makes you think that `print(b.a)` is "much easier" than `print(b)`?

Comment: @Goyo That is interesting. It's not about to print something out rather it may make life easier by not using `global` or make another same variable in a new function. Maybe??

Comment: @Goyo def func():
       a = [1,2,3,4,5]
  
   def func2():
       b = func()
       b.a[0] = "Not Working"
       print(b)
 
  func2()

Comment: @Goyo Updated again

Comment: What do you expect `b` to be in the examples at the bottom? What should `print(b)` actually print?

Comment: @Goyo for func2 and 3 [‘not working’, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Wait. print(b.a) makes more sense.

Comment: So what would the code that demonstrates your point be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function (in your case a procedure since it does not return anything) is a treatment on data, not a data holder like an object or a structure. When you write b = func() you expect to get the result of func(). You don't have to know what happens in func. a in your function is an internal variable that might be garbage collected at the end of the function (no one referencing it)

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaking `class variables` with `functions variables`

```
# This a Class
class MyFunctions():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # This is a function of the class
    def func1():
        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        return a

# This is a Procedure, it is not function because it returns Nothing or None
def func2():

    b = MyFunctions.func1()
    print(b[0])

    # a variable of the class
    MyFunctions.func1.a = 3
    f = MyFunctions.func1.a
    print(f)

func2()
```

Comment: Yes that works. But I was wondering why Python wasn't meant to built like one I did.

Comment: I will use ';' to separate the code, `b = func1(); print(type(func1())); result: <class 'function'>, print(type(b)); result: <class 'list'>`; b is a list, and lists are types of variables in python, it is the same as saying, `a = 2; a.c = 3;` a variable can not handle another variable at least in python!

Comment: Thanks to you! Your help matters.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't say `return` in the `func1` function, so you should do:

```
def func1():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    return a

def func2():
    b = func1()
    print(b[0])
```